# FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl and url hash propogation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC Forms site and when I go to a page like below that needs to be authenticed I get redirected to the login page, WITH the hash value.  I am doing some dynamic login url stuff and have no idea how asp.net gets the hash on the redirect like so since its client based.  Does FormsAuthentication somehow handle the hash on the redirect?  I want to do the same thing for my dynamic login url.

**Authenticated Page**

```
https://localhost:44360/directors#events/event?eventid=169830
```

**Login Page With Hash**

```
https://localhost:44360/login?ReturnUrl=%2fdirectors#events/event?eventid=169830
```

Even Fiddler doesnt show it

[image]